# add unique unordered sets to list

Tags: python, algorithm

I have to create unique, unordered sets of 2 elements each from a list of numbers. Then insert each set into a list.

Eg:

1. setslist = [(2,1)]
2. uniquenumbers = [1,2,3]
3. unique sets- (1,2),(2,3),(1,3)
4. insert each set in `setslist` if it doesnt already exists. (Sets are unordered. So (1,2) is same as (2,1))
5. Final `setslist = [(2,1),(2,3),(1,3)]`

What is the most optimized solution in python?

Comment: Does `setslist` have to be ordered?

Comment: I mean the list itself. Can it be a `set` instead of a `list`?

Comment: yes, that will also do..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import itertools
existing_sets = set(frozenset(x) for x in setslist)
new_sets = set(frozenset(x) for x in itertools.combinations(uniquenumbers, 2))
setslist = list(existing_sets | new_sets)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> lis=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> [x for x in combinations(lis,2)]
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `frozenset`s instead, and add them to a `set`.

Comment: Of creating a `frozenset`, or of adding items to a `set`?

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Ignacio's advice about `frozenset`:

```
In [1]: from itertools import combinations

In [2]: sets = set([frozenset([1, 2])])

In [3]: uniquenumbers = [1,2,3]

In [4]: sets.update(map(frozenset, combinations(uniquenumbers, 2)))

In [5]: sets
Out[5]: set([frozenset([1, 3]), frozenset([1, 2]), frozenset([2, 3])])
```